# how to fix "then" in geolocation

Tags: angular, ionic3

"Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)"

```
initMap(): Promise<any> {

    this.mapInitialised = true;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

        // UNCOMMENT FOR NORMAL USE
        //let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.713744, -74.009056);

        let mapOptions = {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement, mapOptions);
        resolve(true);

      });

    });

  }
```

"what can use to replace then "

Comment: And what is `GeoLocation`, where have you declared it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the client does not support the Geolocation feature.

You can fix this by checking if GeoLocation is supported by the client with:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
}
```